# Posting dynamic inputs and inserting into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox, multidimensional-array

**This is my schedule.php page, an example of the user selecting the specific day for the time.**

[image]

**Once the user clicks on to add, the confirmation page will show up. But unfortunately i got these errors.**

[image]

**In mySQL database, the values that suppose to belong to "1700 - 1800" appeared on the "1400 - 1600" row.**

[image]

This is my code for the schedule.php page,

```
            <form name="Create New schedule"  class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="handleSchedule.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="AcadInst">Academic Institution</label>

                        <select class="form-control" id="AcadInst" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Institution Name" name="academicInstitution">
                            <option>Institution Name</option>
                            <option>Singapore Polytechnic (SP)</option>
                            <option>Ngee Ann Polytechnic (NP)</option>
                            <option>Temasek Polytechnic (TP)</option>
                            <option>Republic Polytechnic (RP)</option>
                            <option>Nanyang Polytechnic (NYP)</option>
                            <option>Others(Please specify)</option> 
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label>Level of Teaching</label>
                        <input list="LvTeaching" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Teaching Stage" name="levelofteaching">
                        <datalist id="LvTeaching">
                            <option value="Undergraduate Teaching">
                            <option value="Postgraduate Teaching">
                            <option value="Continuing Education">
                            <option value="Others (Please specify)"> 
                        </datalist>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label>Type of Teaching</label>
                        <input list="TyTeaching" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mode of Teaching" name="typeofteaching">
                        <datalist id="TyTeaching">
                            <option value="Clinical Teaching">
                            <option value="Academic Teaching">
                            <option value="Talk">
                            <option value="Others (Please specify)"> 
                        </datalist>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="startdate">Start Date</label>
                        <input type="date"  class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date" name="startdate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="enddate">End Date</label>
                        <input type="date"  class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date" name="enddate" id="noEndDate">
                        <input onclick="document.getElementById('noEndDate').disabled = true;" type="checkbox" name="type">No end date
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Start Time</th>
                                    <th>End Time</th>
                                    <th>Mon</th>
                                    <th>Tue</th>
                                    <th>Wed</th>
                                    <th>Thu</th>
                                    <th>Fri</th>
                                    <th><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Add Timeslot" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="dataTable">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[0]"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[0]"></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Monday[0]" value="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday[0]" value="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Wednesday[0]" value="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Thursday[0]" value="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Friday[0]" value="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br/>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="submit"  value="Add" class="btn btn-success">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

My codes for handleSchedule.php,

```html
<?php

    $con = getDbConnect();

    $academicInstitution = $_POST['academicInstitution'];
    $levelofteaching = $_POST['levelofteaching'];
    $typeofteaching = $_POST['typeofteaching'];
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate = $_POST['enddate'];

                if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                } else {
                    if ($_POST['startTime']) {
                    foreach ($_POST["startTime"] as $key => $value) {

                            $endTime = $_POST["endTime"][$key];
                            $monday = $_POST["Monday"][$key];
                            $tuesday = $_POST["Tuesday"][$key];
                            $wednesday = $_POST["Wednesday"][$key];
                            $thursday = $_POST["Thursday"][$key];
                            $friday = $_POST["Friday"][$key];
                           

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO timetableschedule (academicInstitution, lvteaching, tyteaching, startdate, endate, startTime, endTime, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) " .
                                    "VALUES ('$academicInstitution', '$levelofteaching', '$typeofteaching', '$startdate', '$enddate', '$value', '$endTime', '$monday', '$tuesday', '$wednesday', '$thursday', '$friday')";
                            mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    }
                    }

                    echo "1 record added";
                    mysqli_close($con);
                }
                ?>
```

I am suspecting that the unchecked checkbox are causing the problem. Do anyone have any idea to solve it?

Comment: for one thing, `<select>` does not have a "type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecked checkboxes don't get submitted to the server. So `$_POST['Monday']` is just an array of all the checked boxes. The indexes of these parameters won't match up with the text boxes.

The solution is to put explicit indexes in the names:

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[0]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[0]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Monday[0]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday[0]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Wednesday[0]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Thursday[0]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Friday[0]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /></td>
    </tr>
```

When you add a new row, you need to increment the index.

In the PHP, you then need to check whether the parameter is set.

```
$monday = isset($_POST["Monday"][$key]) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: why "? 1:0" i did not receive any error message this time, but in the database, it did not work correctly

Comment: For a checkbox there's not much point in using the value, all that matters is whether it's there or not. I could have written `isset($_POST["Monday"][$key]) ? $_POST["Monday"][$key] : 0`.